# Homology with Coefficients (Quotient of Tensors)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

In my previous question [Simplifying Quotient of Tensor Products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472095/simplifying-quotient-of-tensor-products), I learnt that even if $B$ is a submodule of $A$, the tensor product $B\otimes C$ is not a submodule of $A\otimes C$ in general, hence strictly $$(A\otimes C)/(B\otimes C)\not\cong(A/B)\otimes C$$.

However, here I am considering a special case, the homology with coefficients (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem):

$$H_i(X;G)=(\ker\partial_i\otimes G)/(\text{Im}\,\partial_{i+1}\otimes G)$$

My question is, is the above the same as $$(\ker\partial_i/\text{Im}\,\partial_{i+1})\otimes G$$?

I understand that this boils down to whether the inclusion $$i:\text{Im}\,\partial_{i+1}\otimes G\to\ker\partial_i\otimes G$$
$$b\otimes g\mapsto b\otimes g$$
is injective? Is it? So far I can't think of any counter examples, nor can I construct a proper proof.

Thanks for any help.

I thought of a proof: if $b\otimes g\in\ker i$, then $i(b\otimes g)=b\otimes g=0$. But my concern is that $b\otimes g$ is 0 in $\ker\partial_i\otimes G$, which doesn't necessarily imply that it is zero in $\text{Im}\,\partial_{i+1}\otimes G$, or does it?

Comment: See the notion of flatness for a module.

Comment: Your formula for homology with coefficients is at best misleading, at worst wrong. Does $\ker \partial_i \otimes G$ mean $(\ker \partial_i) \otimes G$ (which gives the wrong answer) or $\ker (\partial_i \otimes G)$, in which case you have to interpret $G$ as being the identity map on $G$?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri The first version makes no sense in general since $\otimes G$ may not be exact and hence that quotient is not a quotient at all.

Comment: And I don't know if the original poster realizes this. The notation is, as I said, misleading.

Comment: I found this notation on the Wikipedia page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem. Maybe there is an error on Wikipedia?

Comment: Would $\ker(\partial_i\otimes 1)$ be a better notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking if $H_*(X,G)$ is the same as $H_*(X)\otimes G$, and the answer is 'no', in general: this is the content of universal coefficient theorem that you are reading. Indeed, what happens is the canonical map 
$$H_*(X)\otimes G\to H_*(X,G)$$ 
that assigns $[z]\otimes g\longmapsto [z\otimes g]$ is always injective, but there is a cokernel (i.e. it is not surjective) which is $\operatorname{Tor}_1(H_{*-1}(X),G)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it easy to see that the map is not surjective? Any easy examples?